# Не всегда срабатывает переадресация php

Tags: php, redirect, header

Есть такая функция

```
header("Location: ".$urlToDialogAuth);
```

Допустим в первом случае `$urlToDialogAuth` будет `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/` переадресация пройдет на ура.
Во втором случае та же переменная будет `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=500004&redirect_uri=http://i0l0o0h0i00nn.ru.s106.h00h0os.ru/backend/auth/auth.php&response_type=code&display=page&scope=nohttps,groups,photos,offline`

Переадресации не происходит, но! Я думал URI битый, ан нет. Если ручками по нему переходить, то все ок. В чем беда? Нулики специально вбил, пока скрою от чужих глаз :)

Comment: может какие-то условия для вывода есть и раньше header вдруг появляется в выводе что-то. Ибо запрос должен работать так и так

Comment: попробуйте добавить `die();` после `header("Location: ".$urlToDialogAuth);`